# pytest fixture for mocked object setup?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest and I have 5+ tests that have the exactly same first five lines. Is it possible to create a setup function for the repeated code?

```
@mock.patch('abcde.xyz')
def test_1(mocked_function):
    x_mock = mock.Mock(X)
    x_mock.producer = mock.Mock()
    x_mock.producer.func2 = lambda : None
    mocked_function.return_value = x_mock # xyz() returns x_mock
    ......

@mock.patch('abcde.xyz')
def test_2(mocked_function):
    x_mock = mock.Mock(X)
    x_mock.producer = mock.Mock()
    x_mock.producer.func2 = lambda : None
    mocked_function.return_value = x_mock
    ......

@mock..... # more
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixture) as it recommended over classic setup/teardown methods.

From pytest [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html):

> While these setup/teardown methods are simple and familiar to those coming from a unittest or nose background, you may also consider using pytest’s more powerful fixture mechanism which leverages the concept of dependency injection, allowing for a more modular and more scalable approach for managing test state, especially for larger projects and for functional testing.

For your example - considering that `mocked_function` is itself a fixture - it would be:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def mock_abcde_xyz(mocker):
    mocker.patch("abcde.xyz")

@pytest.fixture()
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mock_abcde_xyz")
def patched_mocked_function(mocker, mocked_function):
    x_mock = mocker.Mock(X)
    x_mock.producer = mocker.Mock()
    x_mock.producer.func2 = lambda : None
    mocked_function.return_value = x_mock
    return mocked_function   


def test_1(patched_mocked_function):
    ......

def test_2(patched_mocked_function):
    ......
```

Note that I used [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) instead of mock so that you can use 'mocker' fixture.

If you don't want [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/), just do:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
@mock.patch('abcde.xyz')
def patched_mocked_function(mocked_function):
    x_mock = mock.Mock(X)
    x_mock.producer = mock.Mock()
    x_mock.producer.func2 = lambda : None
    mocked_function.return_value = x_mock
    return mocked_function   


def test_1(patched_mocked_function):
    ......

def test_2(patched_mocked_function):
    ......
```

Comment: In there fixture, the `'abcde.xyz'` is not specified. The test will call the method of  `'abcde.xyz()'`.

Comment: Your example was quite abstract so I wasn't sure it mattered. I just edited my answer to include it as another fixture.

Comment: Thanks. It got error `fixture 'mocker' not found` on `def mock_abcde_xyz(mocker):`.

Comment: That's what I mentioned on the last line of my answer, you need to install [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/). If you prefer not to, just remove the 'mocker' argument and user imported 'mock' module instead (e.g `mock.patch("abcde.xyz")`)

Comment: I use `mock`. However, the actual `data.xyz()` was called (not patched).

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, you do patch 'abcde.xyz' in your example so you can call 'abcde.xyz()' in your test and except it to return a Mock instance, right?

Comment: `xyz` is a function in the module. So `mocked_function` in my question is a function, and it's patched and returns another mocked value `x_mock`.

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example without pytest-mock. Hope it helps

Comment: Not sure how that's possible when the [@pytest.fixture()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.fixture) decorator is set.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my deleted comments. It's caused by a typo. However, the patch is not working. It still called the actual function.

Comment: BTW, the test cases will need to use `x_mock` only. So in my case the test function `patched_mocked_function` will return `x_mock` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222692/discussion-between-jeremyr-and-ca9163d9).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement a `setUp()` (or `setUpClass()`) method.

Another way would be to implement a helper function, as you would in any other Python code.

Comment: Is `setUp()` for `pytest` or `unittest`? The name convention seems `unittest`?

Comment: I think they all use (mostly) compatible naming?

Comment: Ah, you're right; native `pytest` names are different - `setup_function` and so on; https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html

Comment: How can he variable defined in `setup_module` be available in the test functions?